# How to show $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=\sum_{x}(x-\mu_X)E(Y|X=x)f(X=x)$

Tags: statistics, expected-value, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, covariance

I am trying to show $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=\sum_{x}(X-\mu_X)\color{red}{E(Y|X=x)}f(X=x)\\$

**My attempt**

$$\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=\sum_{x}\sum_{y}(x-\mu_X)(y-\mu_Y)f(X=x,Y=y)\\
\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=\sum_{x}\sum_{y}(x-\mu_X)(y-\mu_Y)f(Y=y|X=x)f(X=x)\\
\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=\sum_{x}(x-\mu_X)\color{red}{\sum_{y}(y-\mu_Y)f(Y=y|X=x)}f(X=x)
$$

Just compare the red part, how to eliminate the $\mu_Y$

Appreciate for your help.

Comment: Does $\mu_x$ really depend on index $x$? And on RHS I see a random variable while on LHS I see a real number. Your notation is inconsistent. You should write $x-\mu_X$ instead of $X-\mu_x$.

Comment: @drhab Hi, Yeah. You are right. re-edited.

Answer (score 2):

It's clearer to use expectation notation rather than the series form.

To start you off, first distribute:

$\qquad\begin{align}\mathsf {Cov}(X,Y)&=\mathsf E\bigl((X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)\bigr)\\&=\mathsf E\bigl((X-\mu_X)Y-(X-\mu_X)\mu_Y\bigr)\end{align}$

Next apply Linearity of Expectation and it should start to fall into place for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I still do not see any clear pattern fit onto the title form.Here is what I got $\sum_{x}\sum_{y}(X-\mu_X)yf(x,y)-\sum_{x}\sum_{y}\{(x-\mu_{X})\sum_{x}E(Y|X=x)f(x)\}f(x,y)$

Comment: It is clearer to *keep* it in expectation notation.  Also, don't try to use the Tower Property too early.  Avoid clutter.